# Speeding up Django Rest Framework Model Serializer N+1 Query problem

Tags: django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF `ModelSerializer` class that serializes an`Order` model. This serializer has a field:

`num_modelA = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`
`

```
def get_num_modelA(self, o):
    r = ModelA.objects.filter(modelB__modelC__order=o).count()

    return r
```

Where ModelA has a `ForeignKey` field `modelB`, ModelB has a `ForeignKey` field `modelC`, and ModelC has a `ForeignKey` field `order`.

The problem with this is obviously that for each order that gets serialized it makes an additional query to the DB which slows performance down.

I've implemented a static method `setup_eager_loading` as described [here](http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/) that fixed the N+1 query problem for other fields I was having.

```
@staticmethod
def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
    # select_related for "to-one" relationships
    queryset = queryset.select_related('modelD','modelE')
    
    return queryset
```

My idea was I could use `prefetch_related` as well to reduce the number of queries. But I am unsure how to do this since Order and ModelA are separated by multiple foreign keys. Let me know if any other information would be useful

Comment: Can you share the models? Especially the `ForeignKey`s and the `related_name=`s are important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with an annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count

# …

@staticmethod
def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
    # select_related for "to-one" relationships
    return queryset.select_related('modelD','modelE').annotate(
        num_modelA=Count('modelC__modelB__modelA')
    )
```

in the serializer for your `Order`, you can then use `num_modelA` as an `IntegerField`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    num_modelA = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['num_modelA', 'and', 'other', 'fields']
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I'm wondering now if I need to count number of modelA where modelB.is_active == True how I would go about doing something like that.

Comment: @fictionalPlant: you can use `Count('modelC__modelB__modelA', filter=Q(modelC__modelB__is_active=True))`.

Comment: I added the `.annotate()` to the `setup_eager_loading` method and it was able to reduce the number of queries that are being made, but it ended up actually increasing the amount of total time for the api response

Comment: @fictionalPlant: are there any other N+1 problems with the query?

Comment: There are, I've already solved issues that seem to be able to be addressed with the `select_related` and `prefetch_related` methods. The ones that remain require a similar approach with the annotation, but each one that I try to solve by annotating significantly increases the response time.

Comment: @fictionalPlant: If you annotation on different tables, the two will act as a multiplier of each other, you thus can not use `.annotate` to work on two (or more) different tables.